# Replacing/Changing a File path in the database outside Django default enviroment

Tags: django, django-models

1) I have a model that contains a filename:

```
 class Image(models.Model):
    p = models.ForeignKey(P, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload_to)
```

Because I'm moving the folder structure I want to change the image column records in the database outside of Django.

So, I tried:

```
images = Image.objects.all()
for image_obj in images:
    image_obj.image.url.replace('co', 'assoc')
    image.obj.save()
```

It fails, does nothing;

If I try just image_obj.image I get the following error:

> 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace'

2) I have a similar issue with a JsonField:

```
for key, value in types.items():
        v = value.replace('a', 'c2')
        types[key] = v
```

In this case instead of replacing is saving an empty json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the django `ImageField` is char filed in the database so you can do replace next way:

```
images = Image.objects.all()
for image_obj in images:
    image_obj.image = image_obj.image.url.replace('co', 'assoc')
    image.obj.save()
```

or do [bulk update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) use sql replace function

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

Image.objects.update(
    image=Func(
        F('image'),
        Value('co'), Value('assoc'),
        function='replace',
    )
)
```